# GPO to Allow Auto-Updates at Specific Time

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-10

I'm inexperienced w/ network administration. I just wanted to make sure this GPO looks correct for what I'm trying.

Our server is Windows Server 2012 R2, and our workstations are a mix of desktops and Surface Pro machines all running windows 10. I've split the workstations and tablets into two groups, and applied the appropriately-name GPO to each computer group. I'd like the machines to download updates automatically (I'd prefer they only check for them after-hours too, but one step at a time), but only install them on Monday evenings, and then restart. I don't want non-admin users to be able to override this and install them manually/arbitrarily. I'm OK w/ Windows auto-installing updates that don't require restart (hence the first setting). Does this look correct, am I missing any settings I should be specifying, and what's the best way for me to check that updates are actually occurring as I'd like on our workstations?

[Automatic Update GPO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OtXA.png)

Thanks!

PS: Please forgive the fairly simplistic question; I am kind of forced into the role of managing our IT, but that isn't really my background. Small businesses. /facepalm

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/629197/wsus-gpos-force-restart-and-disable-choosing-updates-w12r2?rq=1

Comment: Yes, that looks fine. As for how often the Windows Update client checks for updates, by default it checks for updates every 22 hours (this is the Automatic Update detection frequency). There is a Group Policy setting to make changes to the Automatic Update detection frequency but you can't extend it beyond 22 hours.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that about the 22-hour limit, but was kind of hoping there was some sneaky way around it. Oh well.

Comment: What does it matter if a user decides to update on a different day?

Comment: Sometimes updates break things that were working, and our employees are not tech-competent. I need to be available after updates in case there are any problems. For example, a recent update made our receipt printers stop functioning, which is a big deal in some small businesses that rely on a paper trail.